# How to use image path instead of base64 string in phonegap?

Tags: html, cordova

I have application with HTML5 & phonegap & iphone native plugins.

Image uploaded & stored on iphone's local storage using native plugin. Then they are providing base 64 image string & we are displying in HTML img tage.

So if there are more than 10 images then they have 10 base64 image string. So it's taking too much time to load the page.

Can we manage like this they will provide sdcard image path & we display in HTML image tag?

We tried but didn't succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [FileTransfer](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer). You can use it to download files to mobile phone file storage, after download just save path and set src attribute of img.